# Matlab function ppval delivers strange results

Tags: matlab

> The Matlab functions mkpp/ppval allow the construction of a piecewise
>   polynomial. The function y(t) = t delivers for t=0.7 the correct
>   result y(0.7) = 0.7,  if the range is set to [0 1]. If the range is
>   expanded to [-1 1] the result should be the same. However, Matlab
>   returns the value 1.7

MATLAB Version: 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)

MATLAB License Number: DEMO
Operating System: Mac OS X  Version: 10.9.5 Build: 13F34

Java Version: Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

```
% Get the value of the polynom y(t) = t in the section [0 1]
y = ppval(mkpp([0 1],[1 0]), 0.7)
% y(0.7) = 0.7

% Expand the section to [-1 1]
% The result should be the same
y = ppval(mkpp([-1 1],[1 0]), 0.7)
% y(0.7) = 1.7 How that???
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for `mkpp`, `mkpp([a b], [cn ... c1 c0])` represents the polynomial cn*(x-a)^n + ... + c1*(x-a) + c0. In other words, the second argument contains the coefficients to a polynomial in x-a rather than a polynomial in x.

So, in your case, your piecewise polynomial is actually x-(-1) = x+1, explaining the 1.7 result you get.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that mkpp shifts each piecewise polynomial onto the interval defined in the first input - meaning that the left edge of the interval is treated as x=0 in the polynomial.

So the first polynomial defined above goes from y = 0 to y = 1 over the interval x = 0 to x = 1, while the second goes from y = 0 to y = 2 over the range x = -1 to x = 1.